# Determinant of matrix exponential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, linear-algebra

I am trying to find the determinant of the matrix

$$\exp({i\sigma.\hat{n}\frac{\phi}{2}})$$

I expanded the above Matrix using the identity

$$\exp({i\sigma.\hat{n}\theta})=\hat1\cos(\theta)+i\sigma.\hat{n}\sin(\theta)$$

on expanding I am getting 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos{\frac{\phi}{2}}+in_z\sin{\frac{\phi}{2}} & (n_y+in_x)\sin{\frac{\phi}{2}}\\ (-n_y+in_x)\sin{\frac{\phi}{2}} &  \cos{\frac{\phi}{2}}-in_z\sin{\frac{\phi}{2}}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Taking determinant of this matrix, I am getting $1+2\sin^2{\frac{\phi}{2}}$
But the actual answer is $\cos{\frac{\phi}{2}}+i\sin{\frac{\phi}{2}}$, Is there any other way for calculating the determinant of this matrix?

Answer (score 4):

By Jacobi's formula, for any complex square matrix $A$, one has that,

$$\det(e^A) = e^{\mathrm{tr}(A)}.$$

In your case, we have a matrix given by the dot product of the Pauli $\sigma^i$ and a vector $n_i$, for which we obtain that,

$$A := i \frac{\phi}{2}\sigma \cdot \hat{n} = i\frac{\phi}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
n_z & n_x-in_y\\ 
n_x+in_y & -n_z
\end{pmatrix}$$

which is a complex, square matrix. Then $\mathrm{tr}(A) = 0$ and we have,

$$\mathrm{det} \exp\left(i \frac{\phi}{2}\sigma \cdot \hat{n}\right) = 1.$$

It turns out matrices of this form are elements of the group $SU(2)$. If we did the calculation your way using your identity, we would have taken,

$$\det \begin{pmatrix}
\cos \frac{\phi}{2} + in_z \sin \frac{\phi}{2} & (in_x+n_y)\sin\frac{\phi}{2}\\ 
(in_x-n_y)\sin\frac{\phi}{2}& \cos\frac{\phi}{2} - in_z \sin \frac{\phi}{2}
\end{pmatrix} = \cos^2 \frac{\phi}{2} + (n_x^2+n_y^2+n_z^2)\sin^2\frac{\phi}{2} = 1$$

giving the same result since you assumed we were using a unit vector $\hat n$. Notice using the Jacobi formula we did not need to use the fact that $n$ was a unit vector but using your identity, we had to make this assumption, and so your identity is only valid for unit vectors.

Comment: Yes your argument is correct, the operator is Unitary, so the determinant must be equal to 1, But using explicit calculation I should get the same answer (i.e, determinant=1) right? But what is the error in my calculation?

Comment: @Muthumanimaran Check my matrix using your identity, and the determinant calculation. You must have just messed up some algebra somewhere.

Comment: Yes I did a miscalculation, I got the answer.